# how get the last week as start date and end date based on date in current week in scrapy

Tags: python, date, datetime, scrapy, python-datetime

how to get the last week start date and end date based on date in current week scrapy (Monday - Sunday)

Example: if date is 04-feb-15, then result should be start_date = Monday(26-jan-1015) end_date = Sunday(1-feb-15)

if date is 27-feb-15, , then result should be start_date = Monday(16-feb-1015) end_date = (22-feb-15)

I have trying this:

```html
date =aaa.xpath('xxx')
if date < datetime.datetime.today():
```

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478553/get-lastweek-dates-using-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) for that.
It has an optional `weeks` argument, which you can set to `-1` so it will subtract seven days from the `date`.

You will also have to subract the current date's weekday (and another one, to even the day since the Monday is `0`).

```
import datetime

def previous_week_range(date):
    start_date = date + datetime.timedelta(-date.weekday(), weeks=-1)
    end_date = date + datetime.timedelta(-date.weekday() - 1)
    return start_date, end_date

previous_week_range(datetime.date(2015, 2, 9))  # 2015-02-02, 2015-02-08
previous_week_range(datetime.date(2015, 2, 13))  # 2015-02-02, 2015-02-08
previous_week_range(datetime.date(2015, 2, 16))  # 2015-02-09, 2015-02-15
```

Comment: `previous_week_range` takes a `datetime` object (like `datetime.date(2015, 2, 9)`, not a list or a string. You should convert your xpath results to a datetime object first. You can use the [`time.strptime` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to convert a string to a datetime object.