# get lastweek dates using python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, scrapy, python-datetime

I am trying to get the date of the last week with python.

if date is : 10 OCT 2014 means

It should be print

```
10 OCT 2014, 09 OCT 2014, 08 OCT 2014, 07 OCT 2014, 06 OCT 2014, 05 OCT 2014, 04 OCT 2014
```

I tried:

```
today = (10 OCT 2014)

dates = [today + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(-4 - today.weekday(), 4 - today.weekday())]
print dates
```

I am getting this error:

```
exceptions.AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce in Python 2.7, can you show how you are initializing your `today` variabe? Are you creating it using the `datetime` object like so, `datetime.date(2014, 10, 10)`? The error message seems to lead that you are not.

Comment: today = datetime.date.today()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question and algorithm don't seem to correspond. Is this what you're after?

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
today = date(2014, 10, 10) # or you can do today = date.today() for today's date

for i in range(0,7):
    print (today - timedelta(days=i))
```

Answer (score 1):

@MarkG hit the nail on the head but if you're looking to get the exact output as asked this would work:

```
import datetime

today = '10 OCT 2014'

dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(today, '%d %b %Y') - datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(7)]
print ', '.join([day.strftime('%d %b %Y').upper() for day in dates])
```

Note that you need to pass the today's date as a string.

Comment: my input is today=item[xxxx] here i have to check the future and past date with item[xxxxx] and system current date for count the last week.. if dates having future and past dates its should be spiked.